# How can i create an array with formed by a specified number of empty lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays

Something that outputs an array of the form, in case i want 4 empty lists in the array:

> [[] [] [] [] []]

Comment: `[ [] for i in range(n)]`  just one line. n is the number you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try a list comprehension:

```
>>> list_of_4_empty_lists = [[] for _ in range(4)]
>>> list_of_4_empty_lists
[[], [], [], []]
```

*Note: Your example output has 5 empty lists rather than 4.*